# Excluding site from HTML comment with 'Google hacking'?

Tags: html, google-chrome, search, google-search, google-search-api

I am looking for a query that will exclude results that match a given pattern.

```
site:example.com -intext:"test"
```

So the results should just show sites where 'test' is not present neither in the text nor in any HTML comment.

Intext parameter works well for excluding sites where the given string is in the text, but for me it is not possible to find any opportunity that match my wish to exclude sites where the given string is in a HTML comment.

Is there any chance to get such results with Google hacking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Google indexes HTML comments.

Answer (score 0):

HTML comments are equivalent to spaces in meaning. It is likely that search engines ignore all comments, since they have no normal use for their purposes. Thus, you probably cannot search for text in comments or use text in comments to exclude pages from results. Consider describing the context and purpose of your search for queries, and perhaps a different approach can be found.

Comment: I am working as security engineer and I want to exclude some specific customer sites that match a specific pattern. So basically I want to minimize my effort for finding vulnerabilities on the requested sites. Like excluding some CMS, frameworks and so on. I also suggested that Google and generally search engines are handling HTML comments like spaces.

Comment: @Marcel, exclude from what? From some specific queries that you use. I don’t see what the idea might be and why you expect to find specific strings in comments or how CMS and frameworks relate to this. In any case, looking for a solution in the direction of HTML comments appears to be futile.